# How to get column name on searching data base sqlite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, cordova

I have a table name CaseTable .I want to get all entries in coloumn CaseName having the same text .

```
CaseName    data
1           data is well 

 2        check

 3         test

 4          data
```

I do like this but getting error

db.transaction(test, errorCB);

```
function test(tx) {
  alert("test")
    tx.executeSql('SELECT CaseName FROM CaseTable where CaseTable MATCH' +"'+ data+'" ,[], testSuccess, testerrorDB);

  //  tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');



}




function testSuccess(tx, result) {


    var len = result.rows.length;
 alert(result+"result");
 alert(len+"len");


}
```

Comment: Thank you for keeping the error a secret.

Comment: There is problem in database

Comment: That is the error message? Really?

Answer (score 0):

"CaseName having the same text" (from your problem description) implies exact matching. That would be:

```
SELECT CaseName FROM CaseTable WHERE CaseName='foo';
```

If you are not wanting strict matching and are not using a FTS (Full Text Search) extension of some kind, you probably just want to use the LIKE keyword (case-insensitive) instead of MATCH and then if you want column matches for your +data+ variable:

CaseName *begins with* foo then use 'foo%' as your +data+ string variable

CaseName *contains* foo then use '%foo%' as your +data+ string variable